# Why are the RSA signatures I generate with openssl and golang different?

Tags: go, openssl, rsa, sign

I use openssl command to sign the message "Test.", output with hexdump

```
# echo "Test." | openssl rsautl -inkey privite.key -sign -hexdump
0000 - 09 1b ce e2 4b 69 86 be-d7 b1 fb f0 ec e4 53 0e   ....Ki........S.
0010 - ef 9c a4 7b db d3 21 d5-3e 78 23 61 89 34 7e bc   ...{..!.>x#a.4~.
0020 - e9 1e 5a e9 f4 40 e6 53-07 e4 dd 1a fe 31 ec 42   ..Z..@.S.....1.B
0030 - 98 a5 07 d4 7e d9 f4 01-2f ba a3 65 18 b7 69 a4   ....~.../..e..i.
```

The hex string is 091bcee24b69...

My private.Key

```
# cat private.Key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBALKZD0nEffqM1ACuak0bijtqE2QrI/KLADv7l3kK3ppMyCuLKoF0
fd7Ai2KW5ToIwzFofvJcS/STa6HA5gQenRUCAwEAAQJBAIq9amn00aS0h/CrjXqu
/ThglAXJmZhOMPVn4eiu7/ROixi9sex436MaVeMqSNf7Ex9a8fRNfWss7Sqd9eWu
RTUCIQDasvGASLqmjeffBNLTXV2A5g4t+kLVCpsEIZAycV5GswIhANEPLmax0ME/
EO+ZJ79TJKN5yiGBRsv5yvx5UiHxajEXAiAhAol5N4EUyq6I9w1rYdhPMGpLfk7A
IU2snfRJ6Nq2CQIgFrPsWRCkV+gOYcajD17rEqmuLrdIRexpg8N1DOSXoJ8CIGlS
tAboUGBxTDq3ZroNism3DaMIbKPyYrAqhKov1h5V
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Generate signature with Golang

```
var prvKeyPem = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBALKZD0nEffqM1ACuak0bijtqE2QrI/KLADv7l3kK3ppMyCuLKoF0
fd7Ai2KW5ToIwzFofvJcS/STa6HA5gQenRUCAwEAAQJBAIq9amn00aS0h/CrjXqu
/ThglAXJmZhOMPVn4eiu7/ROixi9sex436MaVeMqSNf7Ex9a8fRNfWss7Sqd9eWu
RTUCIQDasvGASLqmjeffBNLTXV2A5g4t+kLVCpsEIZAycV5GswIhANEPLmax0ME/
EO+ZJ79TJKN5yiGBRsv5yvx5UiHxajEXAiAhAol5N4EUyq6I9w1rYdhPMGpLfk7A
IU2snfRJ6Nq2CQIgFrPsWRCkV+gOYcajD17rEqmuLrdIRexpg8N1DOSXoJ8CIGlS
tAboUGBxTDq3ZroNism3DaMIbKPyYrAqhKov1h5V
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

func GenerateSignature() {
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(prvKeyPem))
    if block == nil {
        panic("failed to parse root certificate PEM")
    }
    privKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes) //x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to parse certificate: " + err.Error())
    }
    indata := "Test."
    h := sha256.New()
    h.Write([]byte(indata))
    digest := h.Sum(nil)

    s, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privKey, crypto.SHA256, digest)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to sign:" + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", s)
}

func main() {
    GenerateSignature()
}
```

go run this code, following is output:
52e1cce3810c1a89693cf6965d1035618820a9e3a7b95203d885c4153dc3f7424b98e3ba628a186f1074d672bb59a1c0788a9c2064951ca2326eb1bf8e3e49e9

But I think it should be:

091bcee24b69...

**Where is my wrong? Thanks**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the newline added by `echo` described in [helmbert’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209970/214790), the OpenSSL `rsautl` command operates directly on the supplied data, while the Go code first hashes the data with SHA256 and then signs the resulting digest.

To perform the same as the Go code with OpenSSL, you can use the [`dgst` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/dgst.html) with the `-sign` option (note I’ve included the `-n` option to `echo` here too):

```
$ echo -n "Test." | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.key -hex
52e1cce3810c1a89693cf6965d1035618820a9e3a7b95203d885c4153dc3f7424b98e3ba628a186f1074d672bb59a1c0788a9c2064951ca2326eb1bf8e3e49e9
```

To go the other way and sign the raw message without hashing in Go code, you can pass `0` as the value of the `hash` argument to [`rsa.SignPKCS1v15`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPKCS1v15):

```go
indata := []byte("Test.")

s, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(nil, privKey, 0, indata)
```

Comment: With your help, my problem has been resolved, thank you very much.Another question,I get the string "Test.\n" using the following comman:
`$ openssl rsautl -verify -inkey pub.key -pubin -in signature`
`$ Test.`
Bug in Golang,I only found a function VerifyPKCS1v15 to verify the signature,but before call the function, I must have known this string "Test.\n",in order to generate argument **hashed88.
`func VerifyPKCS1v15(pub *PublicKey, hash crypto.Hash, hashed []byte, sig []byte)`
Can I get the string "Test.\n" from public Key and signatrue,just like the openssl command?

Answer (score 3):

The `echo` command prints a string with a trailing newline (`\n` or `0a`):

```
> echo 'Test.' | hexdump -C
00000000  54 65 73 74 2e 0a                                 |Test..|
00000006
```

So in your case, you're signing `Test.\n` the first time, and `Test.` the second time in your Go program. Use `echo`'s `-n` switch to suppress the trailing newline:

```
> echo -n 'Test.' | hexdump -C
00000000  54 65 73 74 2e                                    |Test.|
00000005
```

Comment: just note, not all `echo`  implementations support the `-n` switch.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very useful link.

```
// Sign secret with rsa with PKCS 1.5 as the padding algorithm
// The result should be exactly same as "openssl rsautl -sign -inkey "YOUR_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" -in "YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT""
signer, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, rsaPrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey), crypto.Hash(0), []byte(message))
```

https://github.com/bitmartexchange/bitmart-go-api/blob/master/bm_client.go