# openssl dgst -sign -sha224 generate signature is from with RSA_sign function in my own c code

Tags: c, openssl

in terminal: command is:

```
 openssl dgst -sha224 -sign privateKey.pem -out signature1 someInputFile
```

In my c code, first generate digest of Inputfile the same as command line inputfile, the digest is the same. but when call RSA_sign generate signature, the signature is different? why this situation happens?

[image]

Comment: both the method use same private RSA key.

Comment: Please show the code relevant to the question.

Comment: you can see the answer i post, i copy the code snapshot.

Comment: The signatures are randomized. Also see [Are RSA signatures deterministic?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6515/10496), [RSA signing, same private key but different signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41382110/608639), [Why are the RSA signatures I generate with openssl and golang different?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37202268/608639), [Why are the RSA-SHA256 signatures I generate with OpenSSL and Java different?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13419201/608639), [Multiple OpenSSL RSA signing methods produce different results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38767660/608639), etc...